# How to make a keras layer accept different shaped tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

How to write a keras **LAYER** that accepts multiple inputs? For example, I want to build attention to scale an LSTM layer, in a way that the LSTM layer takes attention and a previous time-features "(batch_size, step_dim, feature_dim) shaped" as arguments? And it has to be done **INSIDE** the layer, not outside.

For example I want something like 'the_layer' :

```
x = Input(shape=(max_sentence_length))
word_embeddings = Embedding(...)(x)
attention = attention()(previous_feature)
lstm_scaled_with_attention = the_layer(return_sequence=True)(word_embeddings, attention)
```

So far I've tried adding an argument to the LSTM layer's call() function but the LSTM derives from Layer class which says it has to take only one input. This is probably not the way to do it.

I also tried concatenate([word_embeddings, attention]) then feed but the tensor has to be aligned in shape or somewhat. I can't get them to go in at the same time. Any ideas how to do this?

----------------------------ANOTHER-ATTEMPT-01-----------------------------------------

To find out what happens if you use it like it's a layer from _Merge, I also tried this

```
x = Input(shape=(max_sentence_length))
word_embeddings = Embedding(...)(x)
attention = attention()(previous_feature)
lstm_scaled_with_attention = Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequence=True))([word_embeddings, attention])
```

In this case, the 'attention' is interpreted as the second argument for LSTM(), which is the initial_state for the LSTM.**call** function. here's the declaration :

```
def __call__(self, inputs, initial_state=None, constants=None, **kwargs):
```

And the error

```
ValueError: When passing `initial_state` to a Bidirectional RNN, the state should be a list containing the states of the underlying RNNs. Found: [<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 72) dtype=float32>]
```

Actually I think the argument can be added here, since passing a list kinda means passing multiple arguments, I guess.

Comment: unless layers that don't have trainable parameters, a layer accepting two inputs would notmake sense, layers keep updating parameters during training, the only thing you can do is concatenate your inputs , since they are not same nature, it wouldnt be useful in anyway

Comment: I wanted to change the behaviour of some layer when they have other value closed by are 'masked'. You can think of the attention as a kind of mask. It doesn't have to be an attention I'm just putting it as an example.

Comment: Layers can take multiple inputs, what is the actual issue? For example, take the merge layers (Add, Concatenate, etc) which take a list of inputs

Comment: I just tried this approach, wrapping tensors into lists then feed them. I fed them into the Bidirectional layer but it gave this "ValueError: When passing `initial_state` to a Bidirectional RNN, the state should be a list containing the states of the underlying RNNs. Found: [<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(None, 72) dtype=float32>] "  But this looks like the correct way tho, I'm trying to make it work. Thanks

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro The LSTM isn't from keras.layers.Merge so I think that's the reason. Also there are shape limits when using _Merge

Comment: No, you should describe the problem and your attempted solution, with code, what you are saying is a misconception

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I added the attempt to the question body

Comment: An LSTM takes one input, the layer and the mathematical computations are defined for a single input, if you want more inputs, you need to define how the LSTM computations will work with multiple inputs, and then you need to implement that in Keras, its not going to be easy. Why do you even want to have a multi-input LSTM?

Comment: I need to change the way the gates work for experimental purposes.